# How to find and delete registry entries in Wix

Tags: wix, registry, wix3, visual-studio-addins

I am trying to write a Wix3 install for a visual studio add-in.

I have it just about there, but I need reset the plugin by deleting a registry entry.  Specifically any value starting with

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\PreloadAddinStateManaged\MyAddinName.Connect;
```

How to a convince Wix to delete any such entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your issue the need to do a partial match on the registry value. If not, then you might be looking for the RemoveRegistryValue element (nests under Component). If yes, then I would think you'd probably need to create a custom action to search for the registry value(s) to delete and populate the RemoveRegistry table with what you find. I would think a DTF (Deployment Tools Foundation) custom action would a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `registry` element.

- http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_registry.htm

This should solve your issue you're having. There is a great [WiX tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/) and registry is discussed in chapter called [Beyond Files](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson1.php#1.7).

Comment: Just FYI, the Registry element is deprecated in v3. The RemoveRegistryValue element seems to be the appropriate replacement in this case.